# Regex to capture single-quoted string in this pattern...?

Tags: jquery, html, regex, escaping

Say I have an element in my HTML page like so:

```
<span class="special caption['This &lt;em&gt;expression&lt;/em&gt; describes this element.']">ABC</span>
```

I'd like to use jQuery to extract this "caption" from the class attribute. I know how to isolate

```
caption['This &lt;em&gt;expression&lt;/em&gt; describes this element.']
```

but what regular expression could let me extract

> This <em>expression</em> describes this element.

?

Bonus points if I can incorporate an escape sequence for the apostrophe, e.g.

```
caption['This &lt;em style=\'color: #FF0000;\'&gt;expression&lt;/em&gt; describes this element.']
```

and get

> This <em style='color: #FF0000;'>expression</em> describes this 'element.'

Thanks for all your help. I'm really challenged at regular expressions....

Comment: I'm guessing you didn't mean to have a `'` character before `element` in your last block quote up there ??

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, I modified my example to use a tag attribute instead of just single quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably shouldn't be putting this info into the class attribute (see locrizak's answer), but if you absolutely have to for some reason, read on.

I don't think you need a regular expression. If you already know how to get it down to this:

```
caption['This &lt;em&gt;expression&lt;/em&gt; describes this element.']
```

...then all you need to do is take that string and substring it, like so:

```
var s = "caption['This &lt;em&gt;expression&lt;/em&gt; describes this element.']";
s = s.substring(9, s.length - 2);
```

Comment: Wow. Duh moment. Thank you... I don't know why I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 2):

`Class` is completely the wrong place to do something like this.

This is the correct way:

```
<span data-caption="This <em style=\'color: #FF0000;\'>expression</em> describes this element."></span>
```

and then you can access it through jQuery:

```
$('span').attr('data-caption')
```

Comment: Of course, the OP might not have control over the HTML being parsed,  thus prompting the use of jQuery... but what do I know?

Comment: I chose not to because I wanted it to be valid XHTML. I considered using the rel attribute, but I wanted to apply other properties in a similar manner. I also considered applying the value to the element with jQuery (i.e. $.data(e, 'data-caption', '')), but that defeats the purpose of being able to define the caption in the HTML instead, which I wanted to do out of convenience.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not the most experienced with jQuery's capabilities, but you might try this expression:

```
/class=".*?caption\['((?:\\'|[^'])*)'/m
```

I know it is capable of finding any `class` attribute with a `caption` class and the formatting you have above from within any string and matching the contents of the single quotes (`'`), allowing for single-escaped single quotes (`\'`).

With this HTML:

```
<span class="special caption['This &lt;em&gt;expression&lt;/em&gt; describes this element.']">ABC</span>
<span class="special caption['This &lt;em style=\'color: #FF0000;\'&gt;expression&lt;/em&gt; describes this element.']">ABC</span>
```

it finds two matches (in capture group 1):

```
This &lt;em&gt;expression&lt;/em&gt; describes this element.
This &lt;em style=\'color: #FF0000;\'&gt;expression&lt;/em&gt; describes this element.
```

I hope this helps you out!

JavaScript does not have look-behind, or I would have provided a solution that matches only the text you desired - it could be done with two expressions, if you are only able to get the entire match and cannot access the first match group.